# Cannot removing an event from my own event delegation system

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, event-delegation

I am trying to write my own event delegation system, and it works great, except that I can't remove the event once I attach it to an element! I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code is in a pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjyZyV?editors=101

And also below:

### Markup

```
<ul id="parent">
  <li class="item">Lorum</li>
  <li class="item">Lorum</li>
  <li class="item">Lorum</li>
  <li class="item">Lorum</li>
  <li class="item">Lorum</li>
  <li class="item">Lorum</li>
  <li class="item">Lorum</li>
  <li class="item">Lorum</li>
  <li class="item">Lorum</li>
  <li class="item">Lorum</li>
</ul>
```

### Javascript

```
Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.matches || Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector;

function isDescendant(parents, child) {
  for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
    var node = child.parentNode;
    while (node !== null) {
      if (node === parents[i]) {
        return true;
      }
      node = node.parentNode;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function eventCallback(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches(this.options.selector)) {
    this.options.callback.call(this, e);
  } else if (isDescendant(this.parent.querySelectorAll(this.options.selector), e.target)) {
    this.options.callback.call(this, e);
  }
}

var MyEvent = {
  register: function register(options) {
    this.parent = document.querySelector(options.parentSelector);
    this.options = options;

    this.parent.addEventListener(options.event, eventCallback.bind(this), false);

    return this;
  },
  unregister: function unregister(options) {
    this.parent = document.querySelector(options.parentSelector);

    this.parent.removeEventListener(options.event, eventCallback, false);

    return this;
  }
};

myEvent = Object.create(MyEvent);

myEvent.register({
  event: 'click',
  parentSelector: '#parent',
  selector: '.item',
  callback: function(e) {
    alert('clicked!');
  }
});

myEvent.unregister({
  event: 'click',
  parentSelector: '#parent'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `bind()`, it returns a new function.
From the documentation

> The bind() method **creates a new function** that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So everytime you call `bind` you get a brand new function, for instance here

```
this.parent.addEventListener(options.event, eventCallback.bind(this), false);
```

it's the same as

```
var brandNewFunction = eventCallback.bind(this); // creates new function

this.parent.addEventListener(options.event, brandNewFunction, false);
```

So you're not passing the function `eventCallback` at all, you're passing in a new function, hence it can't be removed with

```
this.parent.removeEventListener(options.event, eventCallback, false);
```

as you never passed in `eventCallback`, and the functions has to be the same for `removeEventListener` to be able to remove the listener.
The solution is of course to call it like this

```
this.parent.addEventListener(options.event, eventCallback, false);
```

and find some other clever way to pass your options etc.